# Search for the filename inside a tar with a the file's content string (BASH, UNIX)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

I need to find the file inside tar using the file's content value.

For example:

```
a.txt
you are beautiful

b.txt
you are handsome

c.txt
you are pretty
```

I have `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt` inside the tar file I want to search for the file that contains 'handsome' inside all the tar files in my folder.

I have constructed my own code but it searches for the filename, not inside the file itself.

I currently have this code:

```
for i in *.tar.gz; do tar -ztf "$i"; done | xargs grep handsome
```

Comment: Do some (re)search on the internet/SO before asking questions and let us know what you have tried and why it didn't work(or doesn't give expected results).

Comment: I currently have this code...


for i in *.tar.gz; do tar -ztf "$i"; done | xargs grep BTML-55/2013

Comment: While your question is a good one, marked dups answer it already. If that's not answering what you want, we can re-open this.